# python sleekxmpp & gchat sending "invisible" presence

Tags: python, xmpp, google-talk

I am using the python sleekxmpp library to do some work with gchat, my question is: how do I send a presence stanza so that other people see me as invisible (but still be logged on and able to send/receive presencce/messages? So far I have tried `self.sendPresence(ppriority = "0", ptype="unavailable")` but that seems to stop my ability to receive other users presence stanzas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're stopping a bit short of properly setting up invisibility.  After you send "unavailable" you need to send more data in jabber:iq:privacy stanzas, as described in [XEP-0126 Invisibility](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0126.html).  Once upon a time most clients used [XEP-0018 Invisible Presence](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0018.html), but as XMPP became more defined it was realized that that method, though easier, was very non-standard.

The problem is you've told the server you really are unavailable, not just sneakily so.

Comment: Does GTalk implement XEP-126?

Comment: Joe, I'm not sure. http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2008/02/invisible-more-for-gmail-chat.html indicates they may have done it on the web client, google app engine (http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/xmpp/overview.html#Handling_User_Presence) docs don't say anything about it. I suppose I could test it, but then I'd know for sure, and what fun is that?